# vba concatenation only for id

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

Need to concatenate rows for unique id. For example

```
----------
id111 a b
id111 c d
id222 e 
id222 g h
```

---

Need to have

---

```
id111 ac bd
id222 eg h
```

---

I used below code to concatenate non blank values in column, how could I concatenate only for specific id?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Set Rng = Range("E2:E100")

For Each c In Rng
    If c > 0 Then
        Cells(2, 2) = Cells(2, 2) & c
    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

Walk from bottom to top if you may be deleting rows.

```
Option Explicit

Sub qwewreq()
    Dim rw As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, "A").Value2 = .Cells(rw + 1, "A").Value2 Then
                .Cells(rw, "B") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value2 & .Cells(rw + 1, "B").Value2
                .Cells(rw, "C") = .Cells(rw, "C").Value2 & .Cells(rw + 1, "C").Value2
                .Rows(rw + 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm not sure where column E comes into play but you should be able to adjust the above to suit.